# How to calculate a MSSQL query execution time using python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

can any one tell how to calculate a execution time of a MSSQL stored procedure query using python. I have a query like this

```
 import pyodbc

 import timer

 DSN ='DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=255.8.12.34;PORT=1433;DATABASE=CustomerFile;UID=Cust;
       PWD=Cust;TDS_Version=8.0;'

 cnxn =pyodbc.connect(DSN)

 cursor = cnxn.cursor()

 cursor.execute("select * from db.customer")

 d = cursor.fetchall()

 print d
```

i want to know the execution time of the query. I dont know how to do that. Pls help

Expected output:

```
 [(1, aa,vir,123/12, aaa@gmailcom,88898976),(2,bb,yuv,23/4, bbb@gmail.com,2124314)]

 Time Taken To execute: 10s
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
from time import time

# your code here

tic = time()
cursor.execute("select * from db.customer")
toc = time()
print toc - tic
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Got exactly what i want

Answer (score 2):

python

```
import datetime

init_time          = datetime.datetime.now()

cursor.execute("select * from db.customer" )

end_time           = datetime.datetime.now()
exec_time          =  end_time - init_time

print ( 'exec_time  = {} seconds '.format( exec_time.seconds)  )
```